Why does the path traced by a point reflect on a tangent of a circle create a cardioid
I was messing around in GeoGebra and noticed that this construction creates a shape that, at least, looks like a cardioid.

Since both $B$ and $B'$ are equidistant from point $C$, they must be on the same circle.

And since $C$ is on the perimeter of the circle, the envelope of that circle's pencil must be a cardioid ...

image by Ag2gaeh - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0
... which does seem to happen in this construction.

However, I'm not sure how to you'd fully prove that the locus is an envelope.

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid, your construction is equivalent to the one in the section “Cardioid as pedal curve of a circle” (except your construction yields a cardioid of twice the size). There should be a proof included there
